# Strange tag-badge behavior for scala tag

Tags: support, badges, tag-badges

Some users that have overcame the mark of 400 points quite a long time ago still haven't got their silver badges. Is it a bug, or I miss something.

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/scala/topusers

https://stackoverflow.com/users/9815/daniel-spiewak

https://stackoverflow.com/users/354067/vasil-remeniuk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [badges?tab=tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags):

> You must have a total score of 400 in at least 80 non-community wiki answers to achieve this badge.

So if they've answered less than 80 questions they won't get the badge.

Checking the top users page I see that Daniel has answered 79 questions and Vasil 72, so indeed they don't qualify.

Comment: aaaaaah! thx for clarification - I didn't know about `80 non-community wiki answers` rule

Comment: @vasil - also it's 20 answers for bronze and 200 answers for gold.

Comment: I was also surprised by this recently, after passing 1000 upvotes in a tag, but with only ~140 answers. Obviously I need to be spamming more low-quality answers to get my average back down instead of getting 6-10 upvotes all the time. :(