# What's taking my "100 upvotes for tag"-badge? Has it gotten lost on its way to me?

Tags: support, badges

Soooo... I got > 100 tag upvotes (108 to be precise) for the [security](/questions/tagged/security) tag on Super User, but I am yet to receive the bronze badge for that... It's been a little over a week now I think? Is it a bug? Is it a dinosaur? Could anyone shed some light on this? Are there any additional requirements that need be met before receiving the badge for it? Just asking! :D

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange tag-badge behavior for scala tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71904/strange-tag-badge-behavior-for-scala-tag)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quoting from the Badges page:

> You must have a total score of 100 in
>   *at least 20 non-community wiki answers*
>   to achieve this badge.

The reason that you didn't see this is probably that this is only mentioned in the description on the right side of the tag badges page, not in the tag descriptions itself.

Comment: Additionall,y the tag must have 100 questions. (Security has 1k so it's fine.)

Comment: @badps good to know as well!