# Why doesn't this guy have the Gold Delphi badge?

Tags: support, badges

On Delphi's [top users](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/delphi/topusers) list you'll notice Barry Kelly has an answer score of 1.3k but no gold badge. Why?

Comment: I think this has been asked a few times before, such as [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/71904/139095), which I recall only because I was still grumbling about being in the same situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

He's only provided [164 non-wiki answers](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3712+%5Bdelphi%5D+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3A0) to [delphi](/questions/tagged/delphi) questions, and the [criteria for a gold tag badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges?tab=tags) is at least 200 non-wiki answers with a total score of at least 1000.

Comment: In other words, his answers are too awesome to deserve a badge yet.  :)

Comment: The [page for the gold delphi tag](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/122/delphi) only lists the 1000 required upvotes, no mention of the 200 required answers.

Comment: @CosminPrund Hm, good point. I'd support updating the description on that page to include the answer count criteria.

Comment: I only found the 200 answers requirement on the big Badges pages, had to click the "Tags" tab, and even then it's only listed on the Legend on the right of the page. For each tag, it only lists the 1k upvotes requirement.

Comment: @Tim: I might even go as far as suggesting that the threshold should be lowered a bit.  If he's able to attain well over 1000 votes in less than 200 answers, he must be doing something right and the current system isn't.

Comment: @CosminPrund You might want to go ahead and start a [feature request](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=[feature-request]) to make that information more visible.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yeah, the limit does exist for a reason, but I'm not sure the way it's done is necessarily the best way to go about things. At the same time, I imagine most people just naturally meet the answer count criteria, so it's hard to say if it's really a significant issue.

Comment: Yeah, I had the 1000 upvotes for my tag badge at about 150 answers, most of which had a score of <20. :[ It was a bit frustrating.

Comment: I'm not going to turn this into a feature-request, I mostly wanted to know why I got my badge as soon as I hit 1000 upvotes while this guy didn't. I have no bases to support the removal of the 200 answers criteria: Barry's answers really are awesome, but he's also an Embarcadero employee (maker of Delphi).

Comment: @CosminPrund Oh, I just meant that there should be a feature request to make sure that the description on the specific tag-badge page matched the description in the legend on the big badges page.